# Create Table3 AS SELECT WHERE id from table1 = id from table2

Tags: mysql, sql

What I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE temporary_bundle_wired 
 AS SELECT * FROM temporary_bundle,wired_items 
 WHERE temporary_bundle.id = wired_items.id;
```

I have two exisiting tables:

1. `temporary_bundle`
2. `wired_items`

I want to create a third table, called `temporary_bundle_wired`.
In this table I want to insert all rows (and their columns and fields) from `temporary_bundle WHERE temporary_bundle.id = wired_items.id`

I also want to delete those records from `temporary_bundle` once I have moved them into `tempoary_bundle_wired`.

The Query I have tried returns:

`duplicate column name Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Query I have tried returns:
>   `duplicate column name Id`

The above error blatantly indicates that you have duplicate columns. The column names `(id)` in the new table you are creating are clashing between two old tables' common attributes (`temporary_bundle.id` and `wired_items.id`)

Make sure there are no other common attributes between two tables. If present then alias them from either of the table before inserting.

Try this if others are not working.

```
CREATE TABLE temporary_bundle_wired 
AS 
SELECT 
 t.id as id, user_id, base_item, extra_data, x, y, z, rot, wall_pos, limited_number, limited_stack, sandbox  -- and all other attributes you want
FROM temporary_bundle t, wired_items w
WHERE t.id = w.id;
```

DELETING -
This is a different query all together.

```
DELETE from temporary_bundle t WHERE t.id = (select id from wired_items);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both tables have a column named **id**, and your are selecting the two for creating the new table.
You will have to specify each column of one of the tables, so you can rename the id column:

```
CREATE TABLE temporary_bundle_wired 
AS SELECT a.id as 'othername', user_id, base_item, ..., b.* 
    FROM temporary_bundle a, wired_items b 
    WHERE temporary_bundle.id = wired_items.id;
```

Cheers.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gh1vfo. So for each one of the columns in the query i would do... AS SELECT a.id as 'temporary_bundle.id', 'user_id', 'room_id' ETC?

Comment: CREATE TABLE temporary_bundle_wired AS SELECT a.id as 'id','user_id', 'base_item', 'extra_data', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'rot', 'wall_pos', 'limited_number', 'limited_stack', 'sandbox' FROM temporary_bundle a, wired_items b WHERE a.id = b.id;... This did not insert the rows from temporary_bundle where temporary_bundle.id = wired_items.id. All it did was this http://prntscr.com/gh254q. I also need to fill the corresponding fields from temporary_bundle.

Comment: You have to remove the colons: CREATE TABLE temporary_bundle_wired AS SELECT a.id AS 'id',user_id, base_item, extra_data, x, y, z, ... just leave it in a.id AS 'id'

Answer (score 0):

One problem is indeed that `id` is the same between the two tables.  Other columns may be as well, but if `id` is the only problem then use the `using` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE temporary_bundle_wired AS
    SELECT *
    FROM temporary_bundle JOIN
         wired_items 
         USING (id);
```